# Pyspark Count number of non-zero, or zero, in row of RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

In Pyspark as a preprocessing step I am attempting to filter out rows of data from an RDD that contain below a certain number of Non-zero values. Currently we run run a sum that gets called then compared. (At this point None/na has been filled in with 0)

```python
def clean_features(row: Row, nonzero_feature_count) -> bool:
    feature_count = row.features.sum()
    # arbitary filter on how many rows we use
    if feature_count > nonzero_feature_count:
        return True
    return False
```

The problem is not all of our columns have binary values. Some may be as high as 15-20, which obviously would throw off how we were trying to filter.

How can we either count the number of non-zero or the number of 0's efficiently?

So with the row `[1,3,0,0,3,1]` we want to either be able to calculate: '4' for the # non zero values in the row, or 2 for the # zero values in the row. Currently we calculate 8 when presented with that row of the RDD.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, but perhaps you're looking for something like `feature_count = sum(1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in row.features)`? Can't be sure without knowing what `row.features` is.

Comment: OR change than `> 0` to `!=0` if you're dealing with `int`s and they can be negative.

Comment: features is called from this function. array_feature_start_index = 11;
    features = convert_row_to_vector(np.array(entries[array_feature_start_index:], dtype='<S'))